# DevExpress MVC GridView CommandColumn Visibility

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

I set the command column to visible with:

```
settings.CommandColumn.Visible = true;
```

But now when I click on a button on the page, the command column has to disappear.

Do you have any idea how can I do that with JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send a callback to the Grid on a button click with a parameter that will indicate that the command column should be hidden or shown. Use the client-side [MVCxClientGridView.PerformCallback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMVCScriptsMVCxClientGridView_PerformCallbacktopic3845) method:

```
GridView.PerformCallback({colVisible: false});
```

Where `GridView` is the name of the GridViewExtension. In the action method you specified as [GridViewSettings.CustomActionRouteValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcGridViewSettings_CustomActionRouteValuestopic), obtain the passed parameter and save it in [ViewData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.viewdata%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

```
ActionResult CallbackAction(bool colVisible){
    ViewData["ColVisible"] = colVisible;
    // return GridView's partial view
}
```

In the GridView's partial view, set the command column visibility from ViewData as described in the [ticket](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q498632):

```
GridViewSettings.CommandColumn.Visible = ViewData["ColVisible"] != null ? (bool)ViewData["ColVisible"] : true;
```